# Image upload using curl

Tags: linux, image, bash, curl, upload

I want to upload image to remote site using curl cli version, i browse several pages here, but not able to solve my problem.
I log http header in firefox while uploading image:

```
https://www.site.xxx/upload_profile_picture/

POST /upload_profile_picture/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.site.xxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------124439777612656977621176581961
Cookie: 123
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache


BELOW IS POSTDATA:::
-----------------------------124439777612656977621176581961
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="7eddaf78bbd055460167bae9eee3cdea.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic `curl`syntax would be

`curl \
  -F "image=@/yourPath/yourImageFile.jpg" \
  'https://www.site.xxx/upload_profile_picture/'`

Specify other POST data fields with one or several additional `-F` options if necessary, as in `-F "username=xxx"`.

Comment: Hi @Guido can you elaborate more... i tried with `curl -i -X POST -H Header1 -H Header2 ........  -F "image=@/home/user/Desktop/1.jpg" -F "name=profile_pic" -F "filename=1.jpg" https://www.site.xxx/upload_profile_picture/` not working

Comment: @TonyStark What's the error message/response returned by curl?

Comment: `{"status":"ok","changed_profile":"false"}` but Profile picture not changed

Comment: @TonyStark It seems that the image upload worked, but some other data field is missing. Are you sure you're passing all form variables required by the server (username, hidden variables, whatever is in the upload page)?

Comment: @TonyStark Two things that stood out to me: (1) curl calculates and sends its own "Content-Length" header, so that `-H` field in your command line isn't necessary and should be removed. (2) your cookie specification may not be correct. Try passing the cookie(s) as `-b "cookieName=cookieValue"`instead.

Comment: Thanks, i replaced original cookie value purposefully because of privacy matter. however after some digging i found solution. as you gave `-F "image=@/filepath"` so i made new syntax without content header and `-F "profile_pic@/filepath"` so it seems works :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use Chrome, which will construct the cURL command for you in the inspector:
[image]

Comment: By using chrome method i got `HTTP/1.1 408 REQUEST TIMEOUT`